# JQuery template binding is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

In my sample project I am using JQuery template for UI templating by taking the refrence of this fiddle and blog

[Sample Demo](https://footyntech.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/simple-javascript-templating-with-jquery-tmpl/#comment-778)

But it is not working and in my sample project it is giving error

> uncaught type error "tmpl is not a function"

For your reference I have created a new fiddle below . Please suggest based on this fiddle it is giving error.

```
var steve = { 'Name': 'Steve Robinson', 'Age': 22, 'Country': 'India' };

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#person-template').tmpl(steve).appendTo('.personal-detais');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: have you added `<script src='http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js'></script>` `tmpl.min.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

use this below code for appending template.

```
$.tmpl($('#person-template'), steve).appendTo('.personal-detais');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below working snippet make sure you have added `jquery.min.js` and than after added `jquery.tmpl.min.js`

```js
var steve = { 'Name': 'Steve Robinson', 'Age': 22, 'Country': 'India' };

$(document).ready(function () {
debugger;
   $('#person-template').tmpl(steve).appendTo('.personal-detais');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/x-jquery-tmpl' id='person-template'>
  <div class='person'>
    <strong>Name: </strong> ${ Name } <br/>
    <strong>Age: </strong> ${ Age } <br/>
    <strong>Country: </strong> ${ Country } <br/>
  </div>
</script>

<div class="personal-detais">

</div>
```

Comment: Strange things happening in my project. I have done the exact thing . Fist added JQuery JS then Jquery template js then jquery template  and then in my document.ready writeen the code but still same error.

Comment: is there any other js on page?